# selenium code to open and make multiple drivers and options

Tags: java, selenium

I need to make multiple webdrivers and open it at once

I ve tried code bellow..

```
public static WebDriver[] driver = new ChromeDriver[99];

public static ChromeOptions[] optionss = new ChromeOptions[99];

public static String[] opt = new String[99];

for(int i=0;i<=99;i++) {
            opt[i] ="user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\dam\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile "+i;
            optionss[i].addArguments(opt[i]);
            driver[i] = new ChromeDriver(optionss[i]);
            driver[i].get("https://google.com");
        }
```

I need to make 100 drivers that open at once, and each driver opens exact chrome profile

Comment: And what is the problem with what you have (except you defined the arrays to size 99)?

Comment: it open only 1 driver.. code is not working

Answer (score 1):

This Works:

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.clearProperty("user.dir")+"\\resources\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver[] drivers = new ChromeDriver[5];// change array size to meet your demand


    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {// change loop iterations to match array size
        String opt ="user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\dam\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile"+i;
        ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
        option.addArguments(opt);
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(option);
        drivers[i] = driver;
        drivers[i].get("https://google.com");
    }
```

However, there is a delay between each browser opening as the for loop executes.

Hope this helps :) goodluck